# Deleted Apache access logs still taking up space

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I deleted a 7GB apache2 other_vhosts_access.log.1 to free up some space on our server. Basically I deleted all but the most recent access logs. The largest was uncompressed - I assume it hadn't been through logrotate (which is running).

Running a df -h shows no extra space and I have tried every combination of `apache/apachectl restart/reload/graceful` etc..  as mentioned in other questions - with no result. `lsof` doesn't show the file open either.

Comment: What do your partitions look like? I wonder if you might be looking in the wrong place for your free space.

Answer (score 4):

more than likely you have deleted the logs but apache has locked them up.

You should use `lsof` and look for (deleted). IBM guide [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html). The way to fix is to restart the apache process to release the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try to copy /dev/null to your logfile. This should truncate your file without closing the file handle apache is holding...

```
cp /dev/null other_vhosts_access.log.1
```

Comment: The principle is sound but if he's already deleted them, he can't do that.  Writing to the open filehandle in `/proc` may work but I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved as follows.

PROBLEM:

I deleted manually `access_log` and `error_log` in directory `/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite/logs/mywebsite1/` to free up space, but even if the files are disappeared, space is not freed.

SOLUTION:

I used `lsof` sorted by size to search big file (command found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/207143/253461)):

```
lsof -s | awk '$5 == "REG"' | sort -n -r -k 7,7 | head -n 100
```

I found the two big files `access_log` and `error_log` in another path (note the difference with previous path):

```
/var/www/vhosts/system/mywebsite1/logs/
```

I reset these two files with command:

```
:>/var/www/vhosts/system/mywebsite1/logs/access_log

:>/var/www/vhosts/system/mywebsite1/logs/error_log
```

The files have been emptied and the space is freed.

Hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to restart `rsyslog`, which is the one that handles logs on my ubuntu system and it did released all the disk space.

This can be restarted running `sudo service rsyslog restart` or if you are on 16.04+ with `sudo systemctl restart rsyslog`.